# Windows 10 Store got corrupted

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store

My windows store got corrupted. I tried to fix it using SFC and DISM but it didn't work. I also believed that buy deleting the programs file I would fix it but nope it didn't. Then, I tried using powershell but is still didn't work. Do you guys have any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some specifics about how you came to the conclusion that your Windows Store "got corrupted". Error messages, log entries, screenshots, ... We can't tell you how to fix it if we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: You have exhausted your options.  I suggest you perform a Reset. .

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more specific information about how did you fix it using powershell? 
were there any error messages when running DISM command?
Please confirm whether you using the following command in the PowerShell to fix this issue
"Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}"

If the issue persists, we could try to perform a clean boot to have a try.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135
In addition, Windows Store is built-in app, it will be reinstalled for user account. we could create a new account to have a test.
how to fix corrupted user profile.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-corrupted-user-profile#1TC=windows-7

Best regards